# How to use ng-if in front end if my condition is in saved in cookies?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, session-cookies, angular-ng-if

As I've started learning angulerjs I'm facing small issues. while developing angulerjs application.

I've setup login process recently, now I'm stuck on front-end display.
if the user is logged in I want to display specific content.
for example:

```
 <!--show this if cookies is set to true -->
<li><a href="#/logout"><span class="icon mail"></span>Logout</a></li>
<!-- show this if cookies is undefined -->
<li><a href="#/login"><span class="icon mail"></span>Login</a></li>
```

All I know I will have to use ng-if for this.
   how can I check conditions for ng-if, if login value stored in cookies?

**controller**

```
app.controller('AngularLoginController', ['$scope', '$http','$cookies', 
function($scope, $http, $cookies) {  
    $scope.loginForm = function() {         
            $http.post("login.php", {
            'email' :$scope.inputData.email,
            'password':$scope.inputData.password
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);                  
                if ( data == 'correct') {                   
                var loggedIn = $cookies.get('loggedIn');
                // Setting a cookie
                $cookies.put('loggedIn', true);
                //window.location.href = 'welcome_dashboard.php';
            } 
            else {
                $scope.errorMsg = "Invalid Email and Password";
            }
        })
        }

    }]);
```

Comment: By reading the cookie value from your controller, and exposing it in the scope. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

Comment: how to read that value on the front end? I can alert cookie value inside controller but I don't know how to check it with ng-if.

Comment: You need to read the angular documentation, or a good book. This is fundamental stuff. All angular expressions, including those passed to ng-if, are evaluated on the $scope. So, in the controller, get the cookie, add it to the $scope, and then you can check its value from within an angularjs expression. Or expose a function on the scope reading the cookie, and call that function from withing the angular expression.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I'm done with this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an function in your controller to get the cookie here am using simple javascript

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

**check if cookie exist**

```
$scope.hasCookie=function(){
    var ck=getCookie("your cookie name");
    if(ck && ck !="")
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

**Html**

```
  <!--show this if cookies is set to true -->
<li ng-if="hasCookie()"><a href="#/logout"><span class="icon mail"></span>Logout</a></li>
<!-- show this if cookies is undefined -->
<li  ng-if="!hasCookie()"><a href="#/login"><span class="icon mail"></span>Login</a></li>
```

Comment: Than you can use `$cookies.get('loggedIn')` to get the value instead of `getCookie` function

Comment: thank u for ur help. you gave me the idea to work with, I've done this now :)